# Need to install windows service across a domain

Tags: windows, service, active-directory, deployment

Our IT dept wants to roll out a windows service across all machines
on its domain. The machines are running Windows XP. Is this possible? Also, is it possible to have targetted
rollout to a subset of the machines?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  Is this a service that exists and needs to be started and run or something new?

Comment: Also, this question would be better suited to ServerFault. Hold on and it will be moved shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, for software deployment you'd use (or find a way to create) a .msi package and deploy that to the Organisational Unit that contains the computers in the domain. The software would then run as a service, although this would need testing beforehand.

You could also use batch files/login scripts to run the service from a shared area on login as well, although it depends on the enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

You can rollout .msi's and applications easily so a solution may be to compile the service and any changes/registry entries you need into an installation package.